# Failed to render pages. Failed: execute of template. Blogdown 1.6, Hugo Aperó 0.89.4, R 4.1.2,Netlify

Tags: netlify, hugo, blogdown

After an upgrade R to Version 4.1.2, blogdown to 1.6 and Hugo-Aperó to 0.89.4, I can not render my site locally with blogdown:::serve_site() command and I can not update the site at Netlify.

The error I receive

```
 - Launching the server via the command:   hugo server --bind 127.0.0.1
   -p 4321 --themesDir themes -t hugo-apero -D -F --navigateToChanged Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: render of "page"
   failed: execute of template failed: template:
   _default/single.html:3:8: executing "_default/single.html" at <partial "head.html" .>: error calling partial: execute of template
   failed: template: _internal/schema.html:24:82: executing
   "_internal/schema.html" at <.Params.tags>: range can't iterate over
   Data Science
```

Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: any solution? I'm having the same error on a fresh site.

Answer (score 0):

The `tags` field in your YAML metadata must be an array instead of a scalar, i.e., write

```
tags: ["Data Science"]
```

instead of

```
tags: "Data Science"
```

That's my best guess without a reproducible example. If that's not the problem, please provide a reproducible example (you are strongly recommended to do so every time).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error locally when installing any template and following along https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/.

The error happened when I started the server with `hugo server -D` (include content marked as draft). Starting it with `hugo server` worked fine.